# using swagger documentation or Hydra:ApiDocumentation for newly API

Tags: json-ld, hydra-core

I am currently in the process of choosing a technology/format to expose my API. It seems there are lots of discussion on this topic, but could not find the one for future use. I am planning to use **Hydra**:

http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra

as it seems to be fully restfull (hypermedia api) but it seems it is not accepted yet (neither **HAL** is).

when I go to : http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/vocab, I get a json that seems to be what swagger returns.

my questions:
- is Hydra Documentation meant to be sthg like swagger
- could find any tool for it like swagger has.
- I would prefer using Hydra as it seems it has more description on operations... by using json-ld, but it does not seem to be as supported as Hal or swagger is.
-does anyone have experience with hydra

Comment: Did you find a solution that you followed? I am looking for tooling that supports developing my REST API with Hyrda/JSON-LD but I couldn't find any. It is really hard to apply Hydra as the documentation is not completed yet and there is even no kind of editor available. The JSON-LD Playground is good for testing but not really convenient for development.

Comment: nope. did not followed the hydra route and sticked with simple web api (Rest, not restfull)...

Comment: What a pity. Sounds like I should return to swagger.

Answer (score 0):

Great that you consider using Hydra. You are right, we do not have extensive tooling yet but that's just a matter of time. In fact, I'm already working on a documentation generator. If you have further questions regarding Hydra, please don't hesitate to post to our [mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-hydra/). There are a lot of people on that list that will be happy to help.

Comment: This is coming very late but I can't seems to find that such a documentation generator would have been created. 

Is there a way to generate documentation from Hydra API in 2022?